# SD card initialize after some minute it fails

Tags: arduino, sd, rp2040

I am using raspberry pi pico with Arduino-IDE. I need to record analog microphone datas and accelerometer data. Raspberry pi pico has 2 core so I decided to use core 1 with microphone and core 2 with SD card and accelerometer. Accelerometer working at 50 Hz and microphone produce 128 sample at 63ms. I am using nonblocking write example. Actually code is working but after some times (it depends sometimes 30 minute sometimes 2) SD card initialization fails. I couldn't find the problem. I am using [link](https://www.roboshop.com.tr/index.php?route=product/product&language=tr-tr&currency=TRY&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIirfVoN2r_QIVE2HmCh067AqTEAQYBiABEgI4ffD_BwE&product_id=1851) this sd card module and I am using it with 3.3V. I am using this library [khoih-progSDLibrary](https://github.com/khoih-prog/RP2040_SD/tree/main/examples).

code:

```
void loop() {
 unsigned long currentMicMillis = millis();
  if(currentMicMillis - previousMillis > 1)
  {
    previousMillis = currentMicMillis;
    fullData = "{micData: " ;
    for(int i=0;i<samples;i++)
    {
      microSeconds = micros();    //Returns the number of microseconds since the Arduino board began running the current script. 
      data=analogRead(analog_pin);
      fullData = fullData + data + ",";
      while(micros() < (microSeconds + samplingPeriod))
          {
            //do nothing 
          }
    }
   fullData = fullData + "}";
   buffer += fullData;
   buffer += "\r\n";
   fullData = "";
  }
}

void loop1 () {
  unsigned long accMillis = millis();
  if (accMillis - prevMillis > 10)
  {
    // check if it's been over 100 ms since the last line added
    Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345);
    Wire.write(0x30); // Access the INT_SOURCE register (0x30)
    Wire.endTransmission(false);
    Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345, 1, true); // Read 1 byte
    uint8_t intSource = Wire.read();
    if (intSource >= 130)
    {
      readAccel(&x, &y, &z);
      X_out = x / 256.f;
      Y_out = y / 256.f;
      Z_out = z / 256.f;
      httpRequestData = "{\"x\":" + String(X_out) + "," + "\"y\":" + String(Y_out) + " ," + "\"z\":" + String(Z_out) + "}" + ",";
      prevMillis = accMillis;
      secDataBuffer += httpRequestData;
      secDataBuffer += "\r\n";
    }
  }

  unsigned long flushMillis = millis();
  unsigned int chunkSize = txtFile.availableForWrite();
  if (chunkSize && buffer.length() >= chunkSize)
  {
    buffer += secDataBuffer;
//    Serial.println(buffer);
    txtFile.write(buffer.c_str(), chunkSize);
    buffer.remove(0, chunkSize);
    secDataBuffer.remove(0,chunkSize);
    if(flushMillis - prevFlushMillis >= 60000)
    {
     txtFile.flush();
     Serial.println("enters here");
     prevFlushMillis = flushMillis ;
    }
  }
  if (!SD.begin(PIN_SD_SS))
  {
    Serial.println("Initialization failed!");
    if(SD.begin(PIN_SD_SS))
    {
    Serial.println("Initialization done!");
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Initialization failed!");
    }
    
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't give enough information to answer this question in a meaningful way. Does the initialization fail once and then works again on the next try or does it keep failing until a power cycle? A quick glance over the SD library shows that it uses SPI without CRC error checking. This means that any error on the SPI bus could cause all kinds of problems without being detected. Also the SD.begin() function calls 3 different subfunctions. Any of these could be the problem. Unless you can find where exactly the failure occurs, it will be impossible to give meaningful advice.

Comment: @nanash1 initialization fail after unknown minute (sometimes 2 sometimes 50) , I power off and on again it doesn't work.  I take out the sd card and insert it and plug the pico's cable then sometimes work sometimes not.  I tried with SD.begin() function 1 time but it didn't work too.  I am trying new things. This module can work with 3.3V and 5V, I was using it with 3.3V. Now I am trying it with 5V. I will let you know if it works well with 5V.

Comment: SD cards work with 3.3V so the 5V input will just use an LDO to convert it to 3.3V. If it works with 5V then this means that the PICOs 3.3V supply is not very stable or not powerful enough to power the SD card (unlikely). I've read that some SD cards can be sensitive to bad power supplies, so it could be the reason for the errors.

Comment: I took a look at the PICO datasheet and it recommends to keep the load on the 3V3 pin below 300mA. If you have all your external devices on this pin you could be drawing too much power.

Comment: @nanash1 I am using adxl345 and mems microphone.  I don't think they use too much current.

Comment: @nanash1 and I read this sd card module don't have level shifters but pico is fine with

Comment: I manage the get this work. Firstly I am using 5V right now and I delete the        `txtFile.flush();` and `SD.begin();` lines.